# How to install Horizon on Sitecore 10 on Docker?

Tags: docker, horizon

I'm trying to install Horizon on Sitecore 10 on Docker.

In official Sitecore images repository I can see 4 images:

- custom-horizon-assets
- custom-horizon-identity-assets
- custom-horizon-insights-assets
- custom-horizon-zenith-assets

Which of them do I need? Should they be run as separate containers or should I use `db` and `content` from them in other services, e.g. in `cm`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Horizon asset images currently listed in the /community/modules namespace of the scr have issues that the product team is helping us fix.

We will push updated asset images once the fix is in place, the work is happening as we speak and we should have something updated soon.

I take the blame for mistakenly pushing those asset images out to the SCR. I will update this question once the images are updated and working as expected.

Comment: With the release of 10.0.1, is there an update on this?  What is needed to setup an image with Horizon?

Comment: @jflsitecore
we can see the new horizon image with update 1. Is it tested on AKS?
i tried it but it but it is failing to authenticate with the identity server because it can't reach the the identity server public origin DNS name.

Comment: Yes Dylan, 10.0.1 now has Horizon running.

Sameh, we do have Horizon running in AKS. Here's a [link to the Deployment.yml][1] of the AuthoringHost service.

If either of you have any additional questions about how to get this working, please post in #sitecoredemo on Slack.

  [1]: https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.Demo.Base/blob/main/helm/stable/10.0/sitecore-xp0/charts/authoringhost/templates/Deployment.yml

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore Horizon 10 Installation

1. Install Sitecore Experience Platform 10.0.
2. Ensure that your Sitecore CM site is accessible with the https.
3. Enable support for the WebSocket Protocol in Windows Server Manager.
4. Ensure Sitecore Identity is installed.
5. Sitecore Installation Framework (SIF) 2.3.
6. ASP.NET Core/. NET Core: Runtime & Hosting Bundle 2.1. 16 x64.

Ref: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Horizon/93/Sitecore_Horizon_93_Initial_version.aspx

Comment: This answer is not relevant for OP. He wanted to know how to install Horizon on Docker...